# Reactjs hooks cannot read property 'push' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am new and developing simple dashboard in react js.

My App.js file is

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <div>
         <div>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
              <PublicRoute path="/login" component={Login} />
              <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Home} />
              <PrivateRoute path="/home2" component={Home2} />
             </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

There are map function in Home component which is call another component named Deposits.js for mapping array elements on card component.

Home.js file code part is:

```
<Grid container spacing={3}>
      {menuData.map((x) => (
              <Grid item xs={12} md={4} lg={3}>
                <Paper>
                      <Deposits site_informations={x} channelName_coverted 
                      {(x.ChannelName).replace("_"," ")} />
                </Paper>
</Grid>
```

In Deposits.js there is a button, I want to push another page with this button click actually.

```
<IconButton onClick={() => props.history.push({ pathname: "/home2", state: { number: site_info.channel } })}  >
  
          <TrendingUp />

</IconButton>
```

But when onClick, cannot read property 'push' of undefined error is coming. What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The `Deposits` component isn't receiving a `history` prop to do a push from.

## Solution

Assuming your `PrivateRoute` component passes the route props through to rendered components then you can pass `history` from `Home` to `Deposits`

```
<Deposits
  history={props.history}
  ...other props 
/>
```

Or you can just use the `useHistory` react hook from `react-router-dom` inside your `Deposits` component.

```
const history = useHistory();

...

<IconButton
  onClick={() => history.push({
    pathname: "/home2",
    state: { number: site_info.channel }
  })}
>
  <TrendingUp />
</IconButton>
```